# search results page in custom layout using Display Suite

Tags: search, display-suite

I'm pretty new in drupal. I'm using Drupal's core search module for search functionality in my website. Now. I need to customize search results display page to my website theme.
For this I've googled and find that this can be done if you change tpl.php files, but I don't want to change any template files for this. I've also found that Display Suite is most appropriate for this so I go fot it.
 I found display suite search page under `admin/structure/pages`. (Image 1) 
I've edit this page layout and create variant as per my page layout requirement. search form and search results taken from widgets. (Image 2)

Now the problem is I cannot see search results in search results block. How can I display search results in that block. Or is there any other way to achieve this as per my theme layout. Any suggestions or tutorial links will be appreciate..

Thanks in advance...
[image][image]

Comment: Have you set Display Suite as the "Default search module" and activated it in the list of the "Active search modules" under admin/config/search/settings ?

Answer (score 1):

In configuration search setting I "Active search modules" set display suite search and set Default search module as "display suite".